# Java: Using "UNICODE" argument in OutputStreamWriter constructor breaks encoding

Tags: java

I'm learning java these days on my own. I noticed one problem with using `"UNICODE"` argument in `OutputStreamWriter` constructor. I was trying to read from 2.txt and write to 3.txt (both of them saved as UNICODE). But after writing data to the file, endcoding was broken.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\2.txt"), "UNICODE"));
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
            new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\3.txt", true), "UNICODE"));
```

Later, I saved the files as UTF-8 and replace `"UNICODE"` with  `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` in the constructors.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\2.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
            new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\3.txt", true), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Then it started working correctly. So I'm wondering why `"UNICODE"` argument does't work in a proper way in `OutputStreamWriter` constructor. I remember using it before and everything worked fine.

Comment: UNICODE is not a valid encoding. `UTF-8` **or** `UTF-16` are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use valid encoding.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\2.txt"), "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: If "UNICODE" was not a valid argument, it would be rejected be IDEA. For example, when I try to put "asdf" as an argument, it says unknown encoding.

Comment: It would not because you are passing the right argument to the method, a `String`.

Comment: Thanks for answering)

Comment: But... when I try to put "asdf" as an argument, it gives an error and says unknown encoding.

Comment: @YuriiKoval Do not assume that your IDE knows everything about the language it is supposed to support. Trust what the language/code actually produces, rather than what your IDE tells you.